# 'QGIS QUIT UNEXPECTEDLY' while opening

Tags: qgis, mac

I want to anticipate that I know nothing about programming and I am a new university student in the world of QGIS.

Today I tried to turn on QGIS on my mac(Finder version: 10.13.6) to continue to work for a lab at university, but during startup it crashed saying: 'Unexpected quit of QGis'.

I tried to uninstalled it completely (Version: 3.4.13) and reinstalled it but happened anyway, also doing the same process with the last version of QGis downloadable (Version: 3.10 I think), but the result was always the same.

Can someone help me pls? I'm desperate.

The complete error text is quite long.
The following link is a *Word* document with the error text, on my google drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l4lZKFLAvkF0vyiEJRp0MM4ocn6hrEeL

I attach some screenshots of it, if it can help somehow.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful to have the text of the error messages, not screenshots if possible.

Comment: I don't know anything about mac. If this happened on Windows I would tell you: Try with a clean profile: go to `\AppData\Local` and `\AppData\Roaming` user folders, find and delete the folders named QGIS there and run it again. If you could find the equivalent in mac to delete the QGIS profile files for your user (those files are still there even if you uninstall QGIS, so I think it can help, because you reinstalled QGIS and the problem persists), you should try it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l4lZKFLAvkF0vyiEJRp0MM4ocn6hrEeL

Comment: this is the link of my google drive about the bugs